# formatting output in java using printf

Tags: java, output

I have this code and I'm trying to format the output as shown below, but when I start the program and reach to printf, it stops and gives error `Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String`

```
variables:    
itemcode=integer
selecteditems=string
perkg=double
userkg=string
quantity-integer 
dry=string
total=double
```

Note: those are changeable variables into for loop.

```
System.out.printf("%-4d %-13s %8.2f %8.2f %-8d %-10s %8.2f %n", itemcode,
    selecteditems, per_kg, userkg, quantity, dry, total);
```

Comment: It would help to know the values and types of these variables

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I receiving IllegalFormatConversionException in Java for this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936327/why-am-i-receiving-illegalformatconversionexception-in-java-for-this-code)

Comment: why `%n` as last format specifier?

Comment: Are you sure that `per_kg`, `userkg` `total` are `float` or `double` type? It seems that at leas one of them is String.

Comment: @Rustam To add line separator dependant of OS (like `\r\n` on windows).

Comment: one or more of these: per_kg, userkg, or total is a string but is in position to be formated by a %f which is for formatting float values.

Comment: @tieTYT I've included the types

Comment: this is `userkg=string` string type and you are using format `%8.2f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `userkg` as a **String**, but you are trying to print it as a decimal.  You need to change the type of the variable to **double**.

When you define a format string, you are telling java both the way you would like your variable displayed, and what *type* it should expect.

For instance, `%8.2f` requires that you give a **float** or **double** as an argument.

If instead you pass in a variable of type **String**, you will get an error:

e.g.

```
float aFloat = 0;
String notAFloat = "";
System.out.printf("%8.2f %8.2f", aFloat, notAFloat);
```

...gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
   java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4045)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2761)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2708)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
at Scratch.main(Scratch.java:9)
```